# Spatio-Temporal (Time and location) Density with R and ggmap

Tags: r, ggmap

I wonder if it possible to create a heat map or an hexagonal bin map that shows not the location density but the time spent in each zone.

My data are a a set of moving object (SP - SpatialPointsDataFrame) that have a geometric and a temporal attributes (see example below).

```
id     timestamp                  geometry
328    "2012-05-06 22:41:46.001"  geometry point
4087   "2012-05-06 22:41:46.001"  geometry point
17347  "2012-05-06 22:41:46.001"  geometry point
30400  "2012-05-06 22:41:46.001"  geometry point
67058  "2012-05-06 22:41:46.001"  geometry point
12169  "2012-05-06 22:41:47"      geometry point
30407  "2012-05-06 22:41:47"      geometry point
```

And a map of this spatio-temporal points :
[image]

Now I would like to be able to show the total time spent for all the mobile objects inside grid cell. The difficulty is that a this moving object can have multiple location in the same cell. What I want is for one moving object inside one bin get the min and max timestamp and compute the time spent in the cell. Then do the same for all the moving object in the same bin. The result is the total time spent for all the moving objects inside this cell. Then I do the same for all the bins.

Basically, what I would like to have is this kind of map, but instead of having the number of moving objects in a bin, I would like to have the time spent :

[image]

Do you have any suggestions or ideas to create this kind of map (if I can do that with ggmap it would be even better :D) ?

Thanks

Arnaud

Comment: without data, more difficult to tell, but have you look into stat_summary2d() in ggplot2?

Comment: Hi @MLavoie Thanks for your answer. My data are pretty much the same as the one I gave in the example. They are spatio-temporal points (time + geometry). StatSummary2D could work but how can I compute the density based not only on the location of the points but also on the time spent in a cell. Thanks.

Comment: is your id = region? do you have more than two entries for each region?

Comment: id is the identifier of my spatio-temporal points.  I can have multiple spatio-temporal with the same id in the same regions (for example if a moving object do not move or move slowly).

Comment: in the ggplot2 documentation (http://docs.ggplot2.org/current/stat_summary_2d.html) it says that you can specify the function in stat_summary_2d(). Here is an example d + stat_summary_2d(fun = function(x) sum(x^2)).

Comment: This could work, thanks ! I have tried to use the "fun" and the "fun.args" but I was not able to achieve what I was looking for. If i understand how it works, the "fun" fonction compute the value of all the objects inside the bin ? I've tried also to add an extra agrument (the id of the moving object) with "fun.args". But it doesn't seems to work.